# Disable menu bar alert during call

Tags: iphone, ios, menubar

I want to disable the menu bar alert that appears below the status bar when a call is going on in the background. How can I do this?

Comment: You can turn off the banner notification in your phone....:) just kidding. Maxim is right, can't be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this menu bar alert is a part of status bar and it can't be disabled on call.